# C# dispose of control

Tags: c#, controls, dispose

Trying to get rid of a control during runtime. I check for it's existence with

> if (Controls.Contains(myControl))

which returns true since the line inside it is run

> Controls.Remove(myControl);

but it returns this for some reason:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can it be a null reference if controls contain that control?

Comment: Posted code isn't enough to show the problem.  What is myControl and how are you using it?  Removing it, btw, does not dispose of the control.  For that, call the control's Dispose method, which will also remove it from the collection.

Comment: I add it during runtime, and want to remove it during runtime. Dispose throws the same NullReferenceException.

Comment: Could it be a multithreading issue, i.e. another thread does something to make the thread that you're talking about appear to be mis-behaving?

Comment: please post more code, this is not enough to determine what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `Controls` is the variable that becomes `Null`, since Controls.Remove doesn't state that it will throw on Null.

See [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.remove.aspx)

Is `Controls` actually a property getter?  Is the returned value dependent on the page life-cycle state, or session state?